# Remove spray paint from floor tile?

Tags: tile

I have a spot of black spray paint on my floor (not sure how it got there). The tile is an outdoor-rated porcelain. I've used soap and water with a rough sponge and a course brush but haven't even faded the paint off at all.  Would paint thinner be safe on the tile?   There's also a small spot on the grout as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acetone or Nail paint remover or Paint thinner. Done  This will do no harm to the tile

Comment: Atze Ton is apparently a music artist (I just learned this). Acetone is probably the solvent name you're looking for.

Comment: It's a good song. Thx, just corrected it

Comment: If it is a slick polished porcelain surface, I would just scrape it off with a single edged razor blade, the type used for paint removal.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails,a steady hand and a razor blade works on less porous tiles. They even make the plastic blades.

Answer (score 0):

As Ride Sun mentioned, acetone or paint thinner should work on the tile but be careful putting it on the grout. You don't want the grout to absorb the paint any further. Try sanding the grout with some emery paper or sand paper. If you're lucky, that will remove the paint.

Answer (score 0):

If the earlier mentioned acetone does not work, I find lacquer thinner cleans many a product off surfaces. Many spray paints are acetone or lacquer based. Some are xylene based too.